# Define "unauthorized connection" vs "authorized connection" (newbie)

Tags: ssh, authentication

Reading the man page for sshd_config, I see the term "unauthorized connections" in MaxStartups.  What is an "unauthorized connection," a connection that was allowed without any authorization?  If some sort of authentication is required, does that not make unauthorized connection impossible?  Would anyone require use of ssh but not require authentication?  If this is so, why does this option even exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `sshd` has to allow clients to connect without being authorized. A client needs a connection before it can initiate the authorization. So at the time where clients connect they are all unauthorized.

There are obviously strict limitations on what a client is allowed to do on an unauthorized connection. Essentially the only thing you can do with an unauthorized connection is to initialize the crypto and authenticate.

Connections normally don't stay in the unauthorized state for long. If the authorization is non-interactive it usually takes only a couple of seconds. If the authorization is interactive it may take longer, but still a short time compared to the typical life time of an ssh connection.

Thus at any given time `sshd` is expected to have only a small number of unauthorized connections and it makes sense to have a limit on the number of such connections to prevent them using up lots of resources. Without this limit an attacker could open hundreds of parallel connections to use for guessing passwords.